# Force low-bandwidth on embedded YouTube clips

Tags: youtube

I have a limited monthly bandwidth allowance. 240p is almost always "good enough" for me (and if there isn't any on-screen text even 144p is usually sufficient).

When I'm on the YouTube.com website, it respects my preferences (well, usually; sometimes there isn't a version that low quality, when that happens it chooses a medium quality from the available range).

Is there any way to force *embedded* clips on sites that *I do not control* to also respect my preferences? Quite often they present much higher resolution, and by the time I've noticed they've already buffered the rest of the clip anyway so changing manually doesn't help.

Comment: Not sure on mobile. A possibility for desktop (which wouldn't help) would be a browser extension. I know that mobile network providers have this ability some how (I have read it in the fine print on ads for "unlimited" data), they use it to limit data use.

Comment: YouTube should use the same settings for embedded videos – make sure you have third party cookies enabled